# flutter target device not showing mobile option

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I am learning flutter and after setting up flutter and android studio I was trying to test app in my mobile..but I am unable to see mobile option in target device section, even though in flutter devices I am able to see my device.

[image]

while creating new flutter project i selected all platforms..and if from terminal i use 'flutter run' then it runs directly on my mobile but no option is shown in ide..

Can anyone please help, why is this happening and how can i overcome this?

expecting to see my mobile device under target device section.

Edit:
flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.8, on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS 5.15.0-86-generic,
    locale en_IN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[!] Android Studio (version unknown)
    ✗ Unable to determine Android Studio version.
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2022.3)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2021.3)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2022.2)
[✓] VS Code (version unknown)
    ✗ Unable to determine VS Code version.
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: Provide the result of  Flutter doctor

Comment: In which device are you trying to install your application? Is it Android or iOS?

Comment: android device..dell laptop..ubuntu os

Comment: @MahmoudSaleh edited and added flutter doctor

Answer (score 0):

Do you see `android` folder in your project structure?

Have you tried `flutter create .` The documentation says `If run on a project that already exists, this will repair the project, recreating any files that are missing.`

You can also explicitly add a platform if missing using `--platforms` param. See `flutter create --help` for more details.